# relationship between function and Function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype, proto

I`m really wondering about the relationship between function and Function..

i read that article **"function inherit the methods of Function"**, so can function use the methods like apply, bind, call, etc

so i checked in the console, using the code below.

```
function test(){} // statement
test.__proto__ // function(){[native code]}
```

ah.. if **"function inherit the methods of Function"** is true,

why is the outcome function(){[native code]}, not the function Function(){[native code]}?

also i`ve checked that the constructor of function test is function Function,
even makes me confusing..

its so weird.. need some help..

Comment: `test.__proto__ === Function.prototype`. The article you read was slightly wrong. It should have said `Function.prototype`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i was wondering about that point if the article is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.__proto__` is the prototype.

`a.__proto__.constructor` is `Function`

```js
function a() { }
console.log(a.__proto__);
console.log(a.__proto__ === Function);

console.log(a.__proto__.constructor);
console.log(a.__proto__.constructor === Function);
```

`a.__proto__` is pretty much an anonymous function for initializing.

Comment: but both the outcome of Function.prototype and Function.__proto__ are same, both the outcome function(){[native code]}.
so does the user_defined function actually inherit the methods of function(){[native code]}, not the Function?? is that the article what i`ve read wrong?

Comment: @jwkoo This is a bit tricky to understand, but `Function` is a function itself, meaning that it, too, inherits from `Function.prototype`. It's a bit special in that way.

Comment: @4castle aha ! i understand.. thanks a lot. so please let me check..
both the Function.__proto__ and user-defined function.__proto__ have same outcome, so Function includes the many user-defined function, anyway all of them inherit the property of function(){[native code]}?

Comment: @jwkoo You got it!

Comment: @jwkoo Any of the fundamental, built-in components generally kind of play by different rules (namely Function and Object), since they are themselves as well. It's weird. =p

Answer (score 1):

`test` is created using the constructor `Function`, what `test__proto__.constructor` will return

the prototype of test is `function () { [native code] }` from where is is inheriting (what `test.__proto__`), and that is why you are able to access 
`test.<some property name>` whose are actually property of `function () { [native code] }`

Answer (score 0):

Both `function test() {}` and `new Function()`, output `function ...` and not `Function ...` in the console, so it is still consistent. That they do it this way is a historical reason, it reflects more what you normally see in the source code.

```js
console.log(new Function() );
console.log(function test(){} );
```